# How can be done Saxon XPath compilation and evaluation?

Tags: java, xpath, htmlunit, saxon

I am currently using htmlunit to get xml so I have xml code as string. I have to use XPath 2.0 so I am trying to use Saxon libraries. However, I did not find any helpful java example. Can you give me a working solid example? I would like to get results in string arraylist.
I am using:

```
//h2//a//@title//string()
```

Answer (score 0):

A guide to Java APIs for XPath in Saxon can be found here:

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!xpath-api

which also points to the Javadoc interfaces.

There are working examples of all these APIs in the "additional resources" download file which is referenced at

http://saxonica.com/download/download_page.xml